# Change Author and Committer NAME & EMAIL for all branches

Tags: git, github

I am using the code below to change author and committer's name and email in git. It works. The thing is it only update the Master branch. How can I run this script again all branches in git for 1 repo. Thanks!

```
git filter-branch --env-filter
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "$OLD_NAME1" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME1"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL1"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "$OLD_NAME1" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME1"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL1"
fi
```

Comment: add `-- --all` at the end of your filter branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not able to get -- --all to work, but this works: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/